# How to split DateTime into Year and Month while summing values?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a Date column as an index as DateTime type, and a value attached to each entry.

The dates are split into yyyy-mm-dd, with each row being the next day.

Example:

```
Date:          x:
2012-01-01     44
2012-01-02     75
2012-01-03     62
```

How would I split the Date column into Year and Month columns, using those two as indexes while also summing the values of all the days in a month?

Example of expected output:

```
Year:     Month:     x:
2012      1          745
          2          402
          3          453
...
2013      1          4353
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html)
[`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) with aggregate `sum` by [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and `rename` for new columns names:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df1 = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.year.rename('Year'),
                  df['Date'].dt.month.rename('Month')])['x'].sum().reset_index()
print (df1)
   Year  Month    x
0  2012      1  181
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` and `sum`:

```
(df.groupby([df.Date.dt.year.rename('Year'), df.Date.dt.month.rename('Month')])['x']
   .sum())

Year  Month
2012  1        181
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Note that if "Date" isn't a datetime dtype column, use

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, errors='coerce')
```

To convert it first.

---

```
(df.groupby([df.Date.dt.year.rename('Year'), df.Date.dt.month.rename('Month')])['x']
   .sum()
   .reset_index())

   Year  Month    x
0  2012      1  181
```